# Android How To Post On Facebook Wall Using Facebook Android SDK - With Opening Dialog Box Every time

Tags: android, facebook, share

How To Post On Facebook Wall Using Facebook Android SDK - With Opening Dialog Box everytime and also need to set the wall text pro grammatically  from my ANDROID coding. please help me to over come this issue .. hoping for better response.. Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

- [Android SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/) ›› [Dialogs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/dialog/)
- [Android Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/) ›› [Step 10: Social Channels](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#channels)

Next time, research before asking.

Comment: Hi @Nitzan Tomer that dialog appears only once for me for logging in. if i have signed in means it simply posts the text on the facebook wall it doesn,t wait for my approval .. how can i over come this...

Comment: That sounds weird, the whole point of a dialog is the display, to post without it is done with the api method. Can you please post your code?

Comment: Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
             
    String text="http:/www.google.com";
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,text);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,"adsfasd");
    
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Message");    
    
    
    
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));

Comment: Hi @Nitzan Tomer  that is the code which i have used to share with the all social network applications which have installed in my device.

Comment: Next time edit your original question and add the code. You obviously haven't read the links I sent you. You are not using the dialog at all. In fact, you are not using the Facebook Android SDK at all, you start an intent hoping that the user has installed the facebook application which can handle that intent. Read how to use the andoird sdk.